# postgreSQL primary / foreign key not complying

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Hi i current have two table a member table with the usual.

members table

```
member_id SERIAL, 
first_name varchar(20)
last_name varchar(20).
```

I have a second table

planner

```
day as varchar
time as varchar
activity varchar
member bigint
```

I defined up member_id as a primary key, not null and unique

I have it set up also that member is a foregin key of member_id

so this should allow it so that only id numbers in members and be entered in planner, yes?

I have four members at the moment with member_id's from 1 - 4 . 
Well it still doesn't allow me to insert data int othe planner table when i try this below.

```
INSERT INTO planner VALUES ('monday','09:00','Rowing',2);
```

to me that should work but i am receiving this error:

```
 DETAIL Key (member)=(2) is not present in the table "members".
```

so i am currently stumped, any help would be very helpful thanks you all.

Comment: Instead of abbreviated table descriptions, please show us the full `CREATE TABLE` statements include the definition of the foreign key.

Comment: `member_id SERIAL` is of type `integer` while your FK is `member bigint`. This shouldn't harm the operation of the FK constraint as Pg knows how to cast bigint to integer, but you really should define the two with the same base type, either make member integer or member_id `bigserial`.

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us, because it sure works (at least based on the information you provided). See here: http://pastebin.com/YrdLLG1Q

Answer (score 1):

it didn't work because inheritence doesn't work very well with foreign keys. with this current version of PostgreSQL

I had to create a rule for it to work

```
create rule fake_ref
as on insert to planner
where new.member not in (select member_id from members)
do instead nothing;
```

Comment: Which would have been immediately obvious if you had shown us the `CREATE TABLE` statements for all involved tables right from the start.